# He looks so healthy that he does not look that old

Tags: modal-verbs, to-infinitive

Talking about an *old healthy crocodile*, one of the friends:

1. He looks way too healthy **to be looking** that old.
2. He looks way too healthy **to be** that old.

Are they both correct? If so, do they mean respectively:

a) He looks so healthy that he **does not look** that old.

b) He looks so healthy that he **cannot be** that old.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to repeat ***look*** in contexts like ***He looks too [X] to look like [Y]***. The normal implied contrast would be between what something ***looks*** like, and what it actually ***is*** (not between what it ***does*** look like and what it ***could*** look like if it looked different! :) So your first example, and first interpretation don't really "mean" anything at all, even though technically speaking they're syntactically valid utterances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can tell from your second example, "healthy" and "old", at least superficially, do not usually go together. In that example, the appearance of health (he looks way too healthy) is seen as being incompatible with being old.

As counterpoint, one might say, "He is way too healthy to look that old."

In this context, the first example is self-contradictory. He simultaneously looks healthy and old, but the use of "way too" indicates that if he looks healthy he cannot at the same time look old. So the first example doesn't make sense.